# How to get the coordinates of the polygon area

Tags: coordinates, polygon, wikimapia

How to get the coordinates of the polygon area:

http://wikimapia.org/#lang=en&lat=49.964473&lon=36.262436&z=12&m=b&show=/20421408/Chervonozavodsky-district

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the place.Search function of The Wikimapia API and enter the latitude, longitude and the name of the place as parameters.

The API returns a lot of data separated in blocks. The one you are interested in is the **geometry**.

You can make tests with the [Wikimapia API](http://wikimapia.org/api/?action=examples&function=place.search) to filter the results to your needs. With the lat lon parameters and the district name you provided I was able to get the area you needed as the first result.

The places[0].polygon is what you need. A JSON array of coordinates.

Here´s the url I used to get the results:

http://api.wikimapia.org/?key=example&function=place.search&q=Chervonozavodsky-district&lat=49.964473&lon=36.262436&format=json&pack=&language=en&data_blocks=geometry%2C&page=1&count=1

Note that in this example i made the request for a JSON result. But you can also ask for a XML if you prefer.

Hope it helps!